# Unable to type character "n" in ubuntu command line interfaces (R, mysql, python,...)

Tags: python, mysql, r, linux, ubuntu

I am having a maddening problem which I hope someone has seen.

I am working on ubuntu, remotely over putty. 
In the shell console, either bash or tcsh, everything is fine. Everything is also fine within vim.

However, when I run an app which has its own console interface, such as R, python, or the mysql client, I cannot type the character "n". All I get is a bell.

For example, I run mysql client, and I get the normal prompt:
mysql>

I can type sql commands which don't contain "n", e.g. "show tables". 
But as soon as I hit an "n", it just bells. 
Likewise for the R console, and python.

This MAY have started when I installed R. However, I am not sure because I did not do much on this platform before installing R.

Comment: If this helps, the bell character is `\a`, usually `\x07`, which is Ctrl+G (`^G`).

Answer (score 0):

Have you by any chance installed the "beep" program which is available for ubuntu. This program makes use of character 'n' to generate a new beep.

I think you should do a  "apt search beep" or just try to remove "apt-get remove beep"

Let me know if this worked for you.

Comment: Wow, I really thought that would work...however, it's not installed.